# CSS selectors for different from-to scenarios for sections with alternating background style

Tags: css

### User Goal — Fast design iterations when working with alternating section background styles

By setting 3 CSS helper classes on a `<section>` in a HTML Full Site Editing GUI, I want to quickly create sections with alternating background styles:

1. with the flexibility to determine which section starts the series (not necessarily the first on the pageflow!)
2. plus a ruleset where the alternation series shall end,
3. and what specific background alternation style that series shall have.

Instead of: Selecting multiple sections, style them or give them all certain helper class. And re-do all that each time.

### How I imagine the workflow

On the `<section>` where I want my series to start I would simply set the appropriate 3 helper classes:

1. `.has-bgcolor-alternating` — **The general helper class** which tells to start the bgcolor series here.
2. `.ends-with-section-before-foreign-element || .ends-with-section-before-section-with-class || .ends-never` — **The scope helper class** with the ruleset where the series shall end.
3. `.alternates-primary-secondary || .alternates-funny-sad || .alternates-grey-lightgrey || ...` — **The specific styling class** which sets a color, image-pattern, etc.

### The question:

- How do I write the CSS selectors so that the user intent expressed in 2 becomes a reality? Possible at all?

### Sample HTML code

- With the **auxiliary CSS classes** and the corresponding **behavioral expectations (1-2)** in HTML comments, and expectation 3 below the code block:

```html
<section class=".has-bgcolor-alternating .ends-with-section-before-foreign-element .alternates-primary-secondary">
    <h2>Heading One</h2>
    <p>01 one one one one one. One one ...</p>
</section>

<section>
    <h2>Heading Two</h2>
    <p>02 two two. Two two two...</p>
    <img src="cat.jpg"></img> <img src="dog.jpg"></img> <img src="fish.jpg"></img>
    <p>Two two two. Two blah ...</p>
</section>

<section> … 03 with whatever inside … </section>
<!-- Expectation 1: .ends-with-section-before-foreign-element ends at 03 b/c IMG element follows. -->

<img src="grass.jpg" class="full-width" alt="Another full width element between the full width sections."></img>

<section style="/* Manually set bg-color */"> … 04 with whatever inside … </section>
<section style="/* Manually set bg-color */"> … 05 with whatever inside … </section>
<section class=".has-bgcolor-alternating .ends-with-section-before-section-with-class .alternates-grey-lightgrey"> … 06 with whatever inside … </section>
<section> … 07 with whatever inside … </section>
<section> … 08 with whatever inside … </section>

<video src="water.mp4" class="full-width" alt="Another full width element between the full width sections."></video>

<section> … 09 with whatever inside … </section>
<section> … 10 with whatever inside … </section>
<!-- Expectation 2: .ends-with-section-before-section-with-class ends at 10 b/c another section.has-bgcolor-alternating follows at 11. -->
<section style=".has-bgcolor-alternating .is-alternating-funny-sad"> … 11 with whatever inside … </section>
<section> … 12 with whatever inside … </section>
<section> … 13 with whatever inside … </section>

... further sections and other HTML elements ...

<section> … 18 with whatever inside … </section>
<section> … 19 with whatever inside … </section>
<section> … 20 with whatever inside … </section>
```

**Expectation 3**: If I change section 01 to `.ends-never` as a quick design experiment,

- this applies to any `<section>` element until the end of the page, overruling all other `.has-bgcolor-alternating` sections until page end, like section 06.
- The overriding CSS selector mechanism preferably strong/specific enough to avoid !important values. (Possible?)

Answer (score 0):

### This is currently not possible with CSS alone

- But it is possible with JavaScript to traverse the DOM and set auxiliary classes accordingly and then create CSS selectors which works with these.
- One further difficulty with the CSS selectors worth knowing: CSS positional pseudoclass selectors like `:nth-of-type()` or `:nth-child()` have just a single positional number series :nth-of-type() in the document or :nth-child() of the parent.
- The number series does NOT get restarted at any extra matches you may prefix, such as:

  - `:not(section) + section:nth-of-type(odd) { background: grey; }`
  - The section:nth-of-type() is just a single number series in the body root level. It is NOT restarted when the `:not(section)` matches the 2nd, 3rd, 4th … time. But instead continues.
  - Therefore it is sadly not possible to restart the alternating background color series always with the first element of a certain type after another certain element.
  - So you need to handle the series and their restarting entirely in JavaScript and CSS does just normal classes like `bg-style-a {...} bg-style-b {...} bg-style-c {...} bg-style-c {...}`

### The alternative in Full Site Editor UIs:

- Wrap your alternating bg-color DIVs in a parent DIV which simply use :nth-child(odd) and :nth-child(even) to format the series contained in it.
- I wanted to avoid that extra nesting. But that is the only practical way at the moment.